# Getting the average grey scale of each channel (R,G,B) of a pic [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, rgb, average, grayscale

**STILL NEED HELP, ANSERWS WERE NOT THE THING I WAS LOOKING FOR!**

I need a function that gets me the average grey scale of each channel (R,G,B) of an image

```
ave = getAverageGreyScale(image)
```

**ave** must return a vector of 3 elements. Each one with the average grey scale of one channel (R,G,B):

> [ a b c ] 
>  a = average greyscale of R
>  b = average greyscale of
>   G
>  c = average greyscale of B

Still ned help! Can anyone give me a help with this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "canonical" formula for a greyscale value (see [Poynton's Color FAQ](http://www.poynton.com/notes/colour_and_gamma/ColorFAQ.html#RTFToC11)) is 0.299R + 0.587G + 0.114B. If each of your channels is a vector, then getting a vector of the greyscale values is trivial.

Comment: That's what I need. that function must return a vector of 3 elements. Each one with the average grey scale of one channel (R,G,B)

Comment: Do you want the average over the entire image?  That would involve iterating over the image, summing the channel values, and then dividing by the number of pixels.  Apply Chris's scaling factors above if you wish.

Comment: I need the average of each channel of one image. That function must return 3 things. 1: Average of R. 2: Average of G. 3: Average of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
function [Ravg, Gavg, Bavg] = getAverageRGBValues(I)

Ravg = mean(mean(I(:, :, 1)));
Gavg = mean(mean(I(:, :, 2)));
Bavg = mean(mean(I(:, :, 3)));
```

Assuming I is a `rows x cols x 3` matrix (which is what you get from, e.g., `imread`).

Comment: dantswain, thanks, but, for example, from my sample imagen the Bavg result give me an "129.932" which is a number greater than 100. Can be this result right?

Comment: Yes, the numbers probably range from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 1):

Edit after clarification:

You need the average along dimensions 1 & 2, use:

```
ave = mean(mean(image,2),1);
```

---

Original answer:

If (as it is usage) your image is a 3 dimension matrix with last dimension length of 3, you simply can use:

```
ave=squeeze(mean(image,3)); %#compute the average value for each pixel along the third dimension
```

The average is a rough estimate of luminance but a better approach would be to first multiply each color plane by a different coefficient since red, green and blue do not amount equaly to luminance. [Standard coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) are:

- 0.3  for red
- 0.59 for green
- 0.11 for blue

your code therefore would look like this :

```
ave=image(:,:,1)*0.3 + image(:,:,2)*0.59 + image(:,:,3)*0.11
```

Comment: That code is giving me the average of ALL the colors. I need the function to return me a 3 item vector. Each one, with each R,G,B average. I edited my first message to be more clear.

Comment: Hello Laurent, thank you for the editing. Let me ask you something. For example, from my sample imagen the 'blue' result give me an "129.932" which is a number greater than 100. Can be this result right?

Comment: Yes, a computer image typically ranges between 0 and 255. Hence the result in my answer and the one you accepted 4 hours later ;)